00's computer animation featuring a glass sea where time is almost stopped
Does anyone know the name of a computer animation from the 2000's where people lived above the surface of a glass sea (it was the real sea but time in the world was running so slow that the water was solid like glass to them).
I remember that an old man would break the glass with a pick like you do with ice in order to reach something inside the water (maybe a fish? A bottle?).
During the course of a few days a ship would slowly cross the sea and a whale would jump out of the water. Children would circle the whale and stay beneath it, amazed.
I think it was called Glass something or Crystal something but I can't be sure.

It is a 22 minutes long Japanese animation called Glassy Ocean (Kujira no Chōyaku).
The whale scene

The ship scene:


You might want to elaborate in which way this fits the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

I had forgotten to accept my own answer but this is the animation I watched at the time. I recognize the characters and It features the whale and other scenes. Is adding the whale scene to the answer enough?

It might be, it definitely can't hurt.
